# looping on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im busy with a script to load mysql data in php variablen.

My database is an gps tracking database with different users and gps coordinates in a table.
The problem is. each gps update has its own ID... for an example if userA posting his gps location that will be id 1, but when user B also post their location 5 minutes later this is id 2, when userA post their location again 10 minutes later, that will be id 3.

Now is the question. How can i sort the newest gps locations for each user.

This is my table structure and my code:

```
//Tabel selecteren en wat opties defineren
$posities = mysqli_query($raw,"SELECT * FROM positions INNER JOIN devices ON positions.device_id = devices.id ORDER BY positions.id DESC");

//Aantal gebruikers tellen in de devices tabel aanroepen via $aantalgb
$query = mysqli_query($raw,"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM devices");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query); 
$aantalgb = $row[0]; 
mysqli_free_result($query); 

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Naam</th>
<th>Tijd</th>
<th>Lat</th>
<th>Lon</th>
<th>Snelheid</th>
</tr>";
while($pos = mysqli_fetch_array($posities)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $pos['device_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $pos['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $pos['time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $pos['latitude'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $pos['longitude'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $pos['speed'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could use a WHERE clause. I.e.: `WHERE id='$user_id'` and sessions would be an added touch.

Comment: you should be storing the userID of whoever posted their location. If you're not, then you've LOST the ownership information which lets you assign a user to a location, or vice versa.

Comment: If you use auto increment for the `id` you can use `ORDER BY id DESC` and `LIMIT 1`

Comment: You want the record with the max(id) for each user_id. provide an **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)** with some test data and there will be lots of answers.